# Best structure for a GLMM - 3 factors with 1 longitudinal

Tags: r, glm, lme4, mixed-models, usage-statistics

I would like to perform a repeated measures analysis / longitudinal data to the following problem:

> “There are 16 trees that were analyzed in a A region and 16 in a B region. In each region, 8 trees were analyzed in the Winter and 8 in Summer, but they aren´t the same tree. considering that the starch´s perceptual in five different depth about each tree diameter.”

```
tree    Region  season  depth   starch
1       A       W       1       0.07
1       A       W       2       0.10
1       A       W       3       0.13
1       A       W       4       0.16
1       A       W       5       0.11
2       A       W       1       0.07
2       A       W       2       0.10
2       A       W       3       0.13
2       A       W       4       0.16
2       A       W       5       0.11
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
17      B       S       1       0.06
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
```

I think in get a fit on a generalized linear mixed model (GLMM) with Gamma distribution in R. As I am a kind of beginner in GLMM, I would like to ask someone how I perform that fit in R in order to know if the regions, seasons and depth factor cause different effects in the response variable.

It would be correct if I run:

```
require(lme4)
Mod1=glmer(starch~Region*season*depth+(1|tree),data=data,family="gamma")
summary(Mod1)  
?
```

If not, what would be the best way to procedure about it ? I appreciate so much if someone can give me a direction or at least a reference.

Thank you for your help @Ben Bolker and @flies. The contributions posted have helped a lot.
I would then confirm whether or not it is possible to treat depth as qualitative and `Region * stage * depth` interaction. Doing this:

```
data = within (data, {
Region = factor (Region) 
season = factor (season) 
depth = factor (depth)  })
require (lme4) 
Mod1 = glmer (starch~Region*season*depth+(1|tree),data=data,family=Gamma(link="log"))

summary (Mod1)
library (car)
Anova(mod1)
```

Obtaining the following results:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation)
glmerMod]
 Family:Gamma(log)
Formula: starch ~Region*season*depth+(1|tree)
   Date: data

     AIC     BIC    logLik  deviance df.resid
    -1358.4 -1290.7 701.2   -1402.4   138

Scaled residuals:
    Min 1Q Median 3Q Max
-2.3398 -0.6699 -0.1065 0.6683 3.2020

Random effects:
 Groups Name Variance Std.Dev.
 tree (Intercept) 7.171e-05 0.008468
 Residual 6.020e-04 0.024536
Number of obs: 160, groups: tree, 32

Fixed effects:
              Estimate     Std. Error    t value    Pr (> | z |)
(Intercept) -2.593064      0.009621      -269.51     <2e-16 ***
RegionRP     0.260453      0.013607        19.14    <2e-16 ***
seasonV     -0.193693      0.013607       -14.23   <2e-16 ***
depth2       0.409813      0.011894        34.46    <2e-16 ***
depth3       0.594269      0.011893        49.97    <2e-16 ***
depth4       0.779051      0.011893        65.50    <2e-16 ***
depth5       0.432146      0.011893        36.34    <2e-16 ***
RegionRP:seasonV    0.088320    0.019243    4.59    4.44e-06 ***
localRP:depth2     -0.065211    0.016820    -3.88   0.000106 ***
localRP:depth3     -0.130185    0.016819    -7.74   9.92e-15 ***
localRP:depth4     -0.190743    0.016820   -11.34   <2e-16 ***
localRP:depth5     -0.067266    0.016820    -4.00   6.35e-05 ***
seasonV:depth2      0.031624    0.016821     1.88   0.060103.
seasonV:depth3      0.139424    0.016820     8.29   <2e-16 ***
seasonV:depth4      0.147717    0.016820     8.78   <2e-16 ***
seasonV:depth5      0.107589    0.016820     6.40   1.59e-10 ***
RegionRP:seasonV:depth2 -0.018490  0.023787 -0.78   0.436970
RegionRP:seasonV:depth3 -0.113810  0.023786 -4.78   1.71e-06 ***
RegionRP:seasonV:depth4 -0.112337  0.023787 -4.72   2.33e-06 ***
RegionRP:seasonV:depth5 -0.121932  0.023787 -5.13   2.96e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 '' 1

Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)
    Response: starch
                           Chisq      Df  Pr (> Chisq)
    Region                 872.9486   1   <2.2e-16 ***
    season                 282.9125   1   <2.2e-16 ***
    depth                16726.2395   4   <2.2e-16 ***
    Region:season            1.5641   1    0.2111
    Region:depth           521.4171   4   <2.2e-16 ***
    season:depth            85.5213   4   <2.2e-16 ***
    Region:season:depth     49.1586   4    5.41e-10 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 '' 1
```

Could the above analysis be performed? Given the number of estimated parameters, should you consider continuous depth and the additive model?

Comment: It looks like `Region` is confounded by the random effect `tree`.  IDK how `lme4` handles this.  Aside from a few typos, your code looks okay (`region` should be `Region`, `mod1_glmer` should be `Mod1`).

Comment: What are you trying to learn from this model?

Comment: you can use the edit function to correct the typos (below the tags)

Comment: I would like know if the model is correct for the regions, seasons and depth factor cause different effects in the response variable. I would like know if the model is correct for know if the regions, seasons and depth factor cause different effects in the response variable. And how to identify which depths differ.

Comment: you've written `Region*season*depth` (use backticks to get in-line code) - this implies that you expect the effect of region to be different in different seasons and different depths.  note that this effectively means you have 20 different conditions: 2 regions x 2 seaons x 5 depths.  You only have 16 observations, so your model is under-determined.

Comment: I have 32 trees (8 in summer of região A, 8 in summer of região B, 8 in winter of região A and 8 in winter of região B), each tree analyzed at 5 different depths of the diameter. Could I analyze the depths independently in each region and season?

Answer (score 2):

- you need `family="Gamma"` (quotation marks are optional but must be upper-case G). I often suggest (1) using the log link (`family=Gamma(link="log")`) rather than the default inverse link and/or (2) using a log-linear mixed model in this case (`lmer(log(starch)~...)`). Both are more numerically stable than the default Gamma model, and the parameters are easier to interpret.
- Contrary to some of the comments above, by default `glmer` will treat a numeric variable such as depth as a continuous predictor, which means it will assume a (log)-linear relationship and only fit a single parameter. You won't be able to detect "which depths differ", but you will be able (hopefully) to detect a continuous change in starch as depth changes.
- If you have a total of 32 trees, it is risky (low-power) to try to fit a model with more than 3 or at most 4 parameters (max parameters ~ n/10; see Harrell's *Regression Modeling Strategies*), unless your measurements are very precise and there is a small amount of biological variation.  The full fixed-effect model `Region*season*depth` gives you 8 parameters (2 Regions X 2 seasons X (intercept, slope): not the 20 discussed above, because depth is continuous).
- Analyzing depths independently in each region and season is almost the same as fitting the model with all interactions; since you only have 8 trees in each region/season combination, it's going to be hard to fit a reliable model.
- If you're willing to give up on your interactions and fit the additive model `Region + season + depth` that would only be four parameters (intercept + effect of Region (assumed constant across all seasons and depths) + effect of season  (assumed constant ...) + effect of depth (assumed constant ...), plus the random-effect parameter that estimates among-tree variability (after conditioning on the fixed effects) - still slightly too complex but perhaps you can get away with it. (**Do not use a stepwise procedure** where you start with a too-complex model and trim it down to something that looks reasonable. This seems sensible on the face of it but is a recipe for disaster.)
- Don't forget to plot your data, and to check the graphical diagnostics for the model.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The contributions posted have helped a lot. I would then confirm whether or not it is possible to treat depth as qualitative and Region * stage * depth interaction. I added in the question above the commands used. Will I have problems this way? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help @BenB and @flies. The contributions posted have helped a lot.

I would then confirm whether or not it is possible to treat depth as qualitative and `Region * stage * depth` interaction. Doing this:

```
data = within (data, {
Region = factor (Region) 
season = factor (season) 
depth = factor (depth)  })
require (lme4) 
Mod1 = glmer (starch~Region*season*depth+(1|tree),data=data,family=Gamma(link="log"))

summary (Mod1)
library (car)
Anova(mod1)
```

Obtaining the following results:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation)
glmerMod]
 Family:Gamma(log)
Formula: starch ~Region*season*depth+(1|tree)
   Date: data

     AIC     BIC    logLik  deviance df.resid
    -1358.4 -1290.7 701.2   -1402.4   138

Scaled residuals:
    Min 1Q Median 3Q Max
-2.3398 -0.6699 -0.1065 0.6683 3.2020

Random effects:
 Groups Name Variance Std.Dev.
 tree (Intercept) 7.171e-05 0.008468
 Residual 6.020e-04 0.024536
Number of obs: 160, groups: tree, 32

Fixed effects:
              Estimate     Std. Error    t value    Pr (> | z |)
(Intercept) -2.593064      0.009621      -269.51     <2e-16 ***
RegionRP     0.260453      0.013607        19.14    <2e-16 ***
seasonV     -0.193693      0.013607       -14.23   <2e-16 ***
depth2       0.409813      0.011894        34.46    <2e-16 ***
depth3       0.594269      0.011893        49.97    <2e-16 ***
depth4       0.779051      0.011893        65.50    <2e-16 ***
depth5       0.432146      0.011893        36.34    <2e-16 ***
RegionRP:seasonV    0.088320    0.019243    4.59    4.44e-06 ***
localRP:depth2     -0.065211    0.016820    -3.88   0.000106 ***
localRP:depth3     -0.130185    0.016819    -7.74   9.92e-15 ***
localRP:depth4     -0.190743    0.016820   -11.34   <2e-16 ***
localRP:depth5     -0.067266    0.016820    -4.00   6.35e-05 ***
seasonV:depth2      0.031624    0.016821     1.88   0.060103.
seasonV:depth3      0.139424    0.016820     8.29   <2e-16 ***
seasonV:depth4      0.147717    0.016820     8.78   <2e-16 ***
seasonV:depth5      0.107589    0.016820     6.40   1.59e-10 ***
RegionRP:seasonV:depth2 -0.018490  0.023787 -0.78   0.436970
RegionRP:seasonV:depth3 -0.113810  0.023786 -4.78   1.71e-06 ***
RegionRP:seasonV:depth4 -0.112337  0.023787 -4.72   2.33e-06 ***
RegionRP:seasonV:depth5 -0.121932  0.023787 -5.13   2.96e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 '' 1

Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)
    Response: starch
                           Chisq      Df  Pr (> Chisq)
    Region                 872.9486   1   <2.2e-16 ***
    season                 282.9125   1   <2.2e-16 ***
    depth                16726.2395   4   <2.2e-16 ***
    Region:season            1.5641   1    0.2111
    Region:depth           521.4171   4   <2.2e-16 ***
    season:depth            85.5213   4   <2.2e-16 ***
    Region:season:depth     49.1586   4    5.41e-10 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 '' 1
```

Could the above analysis be performed? Given the number of estimated parameters, should you consider continuous depth and the additive model?